# Userid and Password for localhost:631 on Lubuntu Live USB Session

Tags: lubuntu, printing

(Background)

I'm testing Lubuntu for future installation via a live USB.  I'm making sure I can print to the network printer (it works fine on my ubuntu 12.04 actual install).  When I try to set server settings in the printer admin dialog, I get

```
CUPS server error There was an HTTP error: not found
```

searching askubuntu.com led me to try localhost:631 to change the server settings instead.  However, I am being prompted for a userid and password.

(Question)

What is the userid and password to use for localhost:631 on a Lubuntu live USB session?

Comment: Are there any members in the live USB's lpadmin group (`getent group lpadmin`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the credentials should be root's. So set a root password and test it out:

```
sudo passwd
```